# autocomplete in Solr and sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm building a website with RoR and I use Sunspot and the solr Search Engine. I needed to use autocomplete functionality but I couldn't.
I knew that Solr has a new thing called [suggester](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester)  but I don't know how to use this with sunspot and in a rails app.

I found a gem called [sunspot_autocomplete](https://github.com/xponrails/sunspot_autocomplete) and I followed what was written, but when I try to reindex I get this error  :

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: ERROR:unknown field 'tags_ac'
```

The model that is searchable called `Experience` and I put this block in it

```
searchable do
  text :tags, :boost => 3
  text :title, :boost => 2
  text :tips
  autocomplete :tags, :using => :tags
end
```

Finally I found this blog that it sounds good but I don't understand it :(

http://www.binrand.com/post/3338898-autocomplete-solr-architecture-rails-3-2-solr-1-4-with-sunspot-solr-gem.html

I need your help in putting the autocomplete functionality in my app. Thanks A lot :)

Update:
I finally fixed and made a [demo](http://kashaaf.com/) here in the search box.

Comment: Could you share how you fixed it ?? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same "problem" =)

just ensure you have correct schema.xml with "autocomplete" type and fields defined at your solr schema path `http://localhost:8982/solr/admin/file/?file=schema.xml`
(assuming you have local default sunspot dev environment)

for me, i had other one from other project ran at this path (and port)

you can see which one you have in the top of `http://localhost:8982/solr/admin/` as SolrHome

hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem, but I don't think it was related. However, I did find another version of that article that actually includes the code sections that are missing from OP's link.

https://gist.github.com/2648514

hope that helps!